# Is there a way to re-insert items from one table into itself by id?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I basically want to take all the stats in my table that correspond to `stat_id = 3` and do the equivalent of inserting all those fields again into the same table with a different `stat_id` (for example `5`). Can this be done or is a self-table manipulation like this not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(stat_id, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT 5, col1, col2, ...
FROM mytable
WHERE stat_id = 3
```

Comment: @ArukaJ You have to explicitly label the fields, because you need to specify a value from `stat_id`.